# How to extend winforms tooltip text width size?

Tags: c#, winforms

```
private void toolTip1_Popup(object sender, PopupEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.ToolTipSize.Width > 10)
            {
                Size s = TextRenderer.MeasureText(toolTip1.GetToolTip((sender as System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip).Tag as Control), SystemFonts.SmallCaptionFont);
                e.ToolTipSize = new Size(4560, s.Height);
            }
        }
```

I tried 4560 just for testing because with 456 width it didn't change anything i still need many time to add \n or to add environment.newline.

I changed the ownerdraw to true.

I also use the draw event :

```
private void toolTip1_Draw(object sender, DrawToolTipEventArgs e)
        {
            using (StringFormat sf = new StringFormat())
            {
                sf.Alignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                sf.LineAlignment = StringAlignment.Center;
                sf.HotkeyPrefix = System.Drawing.Text.HotkeyPrefix.None;
                sf.FormatFlags = StringFormatFlags.NoWrap;
                using (Font f = new Font("Tahoma", 10))
                {
                    e.Graphics.Clear(BackColor);
                    e.Graphics.DrawString(e.ToolTipText, f,
                        SystemBrushes.ActiveCaptionText, e.Bounds, sf);
                }
            }
        }
```

Comment: What is this thing: `(sender as System.Windows.Forms.ToolTip).Tag as Control`? Why aren't you using `e.AssociatedControl`? + You're measuring *something* with a with a method (the wrong way) and a Font, then try to draw text with another method, using another Font. This is all kind of messed up. It's not exactly clear what issue you're referring to, but if the rest of the code is like this, you may end up setting the size of another ToolTip; or the same ToolTip, but shown elsewhere -- The max Width of a ToolTip is `[Current Screen].WorkingArea.Width`

Comment: Does this post help answer your question? [Text length in a WinForms ToolTip](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51412346/5438626)